# Shell script to run two scripts when server load is above 20

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tomcat

I need a script that I can run on a cron every 5 minutes that will check if server load is above 20 and if it is it will run two scripts.

```
#!/bin/bash
EXECUTE_ON_AVERAGE="15" # if cpu load average for last 60 secs is 
                         # greater or equal to this value, execute script
                         # change it to whatever you want :-)

while true; do
  if [ $(echo "$(uptime | cut -d " " -f 13 | cut -d "," -f 1) >= $EXECUTE_ON_AVERAGE" | bc) = 1 ]; then
    sudo s-
    ./opt/tomcat-latest/shutdown.sh
    ./opt/tomcat-latest/startup.sh
  else
    echo "do nothing"
  fi
  sleep 60
done
```

I then chmod +x the file.

When I run it I get this:

```
./script.sh: line 10: ./opt/tomcat-latest/shutdown.sh: No such file or directory
./script.sh: line 11: ./opt/tomcat-latest/startup.sh: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the permission to execute the files shutdown.sh and startup.sh

Is sudo -s not sudo s-

And I recommend to put a sleep (seconds)

```
sudo -s /opt/tomcat-latest/shutdown.sh
sleep 15
sudo -s /opt/tomcat-latest/startup.sh
```

Or better

```
sudo -s /opt/tomcat-latest/shutdown.sh && sudo -s /opt/tomcat-latest/startup.sh
```

The startup.sh will executed only if shutdown.sh was executed with success.

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, your script is trying to execute the two scripts from the current working directory into opt/tomcat-latest/ -- which doesn't exist. You should confirm the full file paths for the two shell scripts and then use that instead of the current path.

Also, I'd recommend that you create a cron to do this task. Here's some documentation about the crontab. https://www.gnu.org/software/mcron/manual/html_node/Crontab-file.html